# Select an existing variable by using readline

Tags: r, user-interface

I'd like to allow the user of my script to pick an existing object (a vector).

I thought something like this

```
...
message("Select a vector of y values")  
nwd <- readLines(n = 1)
return(mean(nwd))
...
```

but the result is *NA* because *nwd* is seen as a character.
How can I solve?
Thanks.

Comment: `mean(eval(parse(text=nwd)))`

Comment: Maybe you should consider using [shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit safer than `eval(parse(...))`:

```
x <- 1:10

message("Select a vector of y values")  
nwd <- readLines(n = 1)
#input x
mean(get(nwd))
#[1] 5.5
```